# How to save Sign Up ViewController information in Core Data and show that data on DetailViewController in swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have SignUpVC and LogInVC. I want to save User Information from SignUpVC in CoreData. I have segmented control with two options on both SignUpVC and LogInVC called Teacher and Student, if I select Teacher option from segment control then all the data should be saved in "Teacher" and vice versa for "Student". on LogInVC, if user select Teacher from segmentControl then fetch only Teacher data and check if email and password matched and same process for Student Option. segment control: 0 Index -> Teacher and 1 Index -> Student

I have multiple Alerts for different situation to show on SignUpVC:

1. Alerts for all the Empty TextFields to tell user to fill all the details.
2. then if all the details are filled, fetch data from core data with "email" predicate, to know if email already exists and if so then open alert showing "Account Exists"
3. if email doesn't exist then save all the info in core data to respective selected segment control(if Teacher or Student).

Same for LogInVC, I have multiple Alerts for different situation to show on LogInVC:

1. Alerts for all the Empty TextFields (email and password TextFields) to tell user to fill all the details.
2. then if all the details are filled, check if Email & Password Matched or not for respective selected segment control(Teacher or Student).
3. if email and PW don't match then open an alert showing "Account doesn't exist"
4. if email correct and password wrong, open an alert showing "Incorrect Password"
5. if email and PW match -> if selected segment option is Teacher then push to "TeacherUI ViewController" and if selected segment option is Student then push to "StudentUI ViewController"

// SignUpVC

```
// MARK: - Button Sign Up Event

@IBAction func btnSignUp_Event(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if txtFirstName.textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "First Name is empty", userMessage: "Please enter First Name to proceed", vc: self)
        }else if txtLastName.textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Last Name is empty", userMessage: "Please enter Last Name to proceed", vc: self)
        }else if txtBirthDate.textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Birth Date is empty", userMessage: "Please enter Birth Date to proceed", vc: self)
        }else if txtEmail.textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Email is empty", userMessage: "Please enter Email address to proceed", vc: self)
        }else if txtPassword.textField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Password is empty", userMessage: "Please enter Password to proceed", vc: self)
        }else{
            guard let appDelegate1 = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            
            let managedContext1 = appDelegate1.persistentContainer.viewContext
            
            let fetchRequest1 = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName)
            fetchRequest1.returnsObjectsAsFaults =  false
            
            let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", txtEmail.textField.text!)
            fetchRequest1.predicate = predicate1
            
            if (try? managedContext1.fetch(fetchRequest1))?.first != nil {
                Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account Exists", userMessage: "There is already an account with this email address. Please login to continue or sign up with another email address", vc: self)
            }else{
                
                // MARK: - Save Data in CoreData
                
                guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
                
                let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                                
                let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName, in: managedContext)!
                                
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName)
                fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults =  false
                
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", txtEmail.textField.text!)
                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
                
                if (try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest))?.first != nil {
                    Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account Exists", userMessage: "There is already an account with this email address. Please login to continue or sign up with another email address", vc: self)
                }else{
                    let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
                    
                    let data = (imgProfile.image)?.pngData()
                    
                    newUser.setValue(data, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.profileImage)
                    newUser.setValue(txtFirstName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.firstName)
                    newUser.setValue(txtLastName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.lastName)
                    newUser.setValue(txtBirthDate.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.birthDate)
                    newUser.setValue(txtEmail.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.email)
                    newUser.setValue(txtPassword.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.password)
                    newUser.setValue(selectedGender, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.gender)
                    newUser.setValue(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.isStudent)
                    
                    do{
                        try managedContext.save()
                        print("Data Saved in CoreData")
                    }catch let error as NSError{
                        print("Could not save data. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            let storyBoardTeacher = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardTeacher", bundle: nil)
            
            let storyBoardStudent = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardStudent", bundle: nil)
            
            let homeTeacherVC = storyBoardTeacher.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTeacherVC") as! HomeTeacherVC
            
            let homeStudentVC = storyBoardStudent.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeStudentVC") as! HomeStudentVC
            
            if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeTeacherVC, animated: true)
            }else{
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeStudentVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

// LogInVC

```
// MARK: - Button Login Event
    
    @IBAction func btnLogIn_Event(_ sender: Any) {
                
        if txtEmail.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Email is empty", userMessage: "Please provide Email address to proceed", vc: self)
        } else if txtPassword.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).count ?? 0 == 0{
            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Password is empty", userMessage: "Please provide Password to proceed", vc: self)
        }
        
        if txtEmail.text!.count > 0 && txtPassword.text!.count > 0 {
            
            // MARK: - Check Email/Password Matched or not
            
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            
            let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserInfo>(entityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName)
            
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", txtEmail.text!)
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
            print(predicate)
            
            do{
                if let user = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first{
                    
                    if user.email != txtEmail.text && user.password != txtPassword.text{
                        Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account doesn't exist", userMessage: "No account found for this e-mail address! Please Sign up to proceed", vc: self)
                    }else if user.email != txtEmail.text{
                        Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Incorrect Email", userMessage: "Please enter correct e-mail address to proceed", vc: self)
                    }else if user.password != txtPassword.text{
                        Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Incorrect Password", userMessage: "Please enter correct password to proceed", vc: self)
                    }else{
                        
                        if user.email == txtEmail.text && user.password == txtPassword.text{
                            
                            let storyBoardTeacher = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardTeacher", bundle: nil)
            
                            let storyBoardStudent = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardStudent", bundle: nil)
            
                            let homeTeacherVC = storyBoardTeacher.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTeacherVC") as! HomeTeacherVC
            
                            let homeStudentVC = storyBoardStudent.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeStudentVC") as! HomeStudentVC
                            
                            if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && user.isStudent == 0{
                                print("Teacher log in successful!")
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeTeacherVC, animated: true)
                            }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && user.isStudent == 1{
                                print("Student log in successful!")
                                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeStudentVC, animated: true)
                            }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 && user.isStudent == 1{
                                Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Teacher Account doesn't exist", userMessage: "No Teacher account found for this e-mail address! Please Sign up to proceed", vc: self)
                            }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && user.isStudent == 0{
                                Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Student Account doesn't exist", userMessage: "No Student account found for this e-mail address! Please Sign up to proceed", vc: self)
                            }
                            
                            txtEmail.text = ""
                            txtPassword.text = ""
                            
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account doesn't exist", userMessage: "No account found for this e-mail address! Please Sign up to proceed", vc: self)
                    txtEmail.text = ""
                    txtPassword.text = ""
                    
                }
                
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
        
    }
```

i'm not sure of my work done till now. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// UPDATE

// Below Code worked for me

// SignUpVC

```
// MARK: - Button Sign Up Event

@IBAction func btnSignUp_Event(_ sender: Any) {

if checkTextfieldsEmpty() == false && checkValidEmail() == true && checkValidPassword() == true{
    print("All TextFields are filled, Email and Password have correct format")
    
    // MARK: - Save Data in CoreData
    let managedContext = DatabaseHelper.getContext()
    
    //create an entity
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName, in: managedContext)!
    
    //Prepare the request of type NSFetchRequest  for the entity
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults =  false
    
    //NSPredicate to filter NSFetchRequest
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", txtEmail.textField.text!)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    print(predicate)
    
    if (try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest))?.first != nil {
        Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account Exists", userMessage: "There is already an account with this email address. Please login to continue or sign up with another email address", vc: self)
    }else{
        let newUser = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
        
        let data = (imgProfile.image)?.pngData()
        
        newUser.setValue(data, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.profileImage)
        newUser.setValue(txtFirstName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.firstName)
        newUser.setValue(txtLastName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.lastName)
        newUser.setValue(txtBirthDate.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.birthDate)
        newUser.setValue(txtEmail.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.email)
        newUser.setValue(txtPassword.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.password)
        newUser.setValue(selectedGender, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.gender)
        newUser.setValue(segControl.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.isStudent)
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.profileImage)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(segControl.selectedSegmentIndex, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.isStudent)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(txtFirstName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.firstName)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(txtLastName.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.lastName)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(txtEmail.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.email)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(txtPassword.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.password)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(txtBirthDate.textField.text, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.birthDate)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(selectedGender, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.gender)
        
        do{
            try managedContext.save()
            print("Data Saved in CoreData")
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print("Could not save data. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
    
    let storyBoardTeacher = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardTeacher", bundle: nil)
    
    let storyBoardStudent = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardStudent", bundle: nil)
    
    let homeTeacherVC = storyBoardTeacher.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTeacherVC") as! HomeTeacherVC
    
    let homeStudentVC = storyBoardStudent.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeStudentVC") as! HomeStudentVC
    
    if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        print("Teacher log in successful!")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeTeacherVC, animated: true)
    }else{
        print("Student log in successful!")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeStudentVC, animated: true)
    }
    
}

}
```

// LogInVC

```
// MARK: - Button Login Event
    
        @IBAction func btnLogIn_Event(_ sender: Any) {
            
            if checkTextfieldsEmpty(){
                print("TextFields are Empty")
            }else{
                print("TextFields are Not Empty")
                
                // MARK: - Check Email/Password Matched or not
                
                let managedContext = DatabaseHelper.getContext()
                
                let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserInfo>(entityName: ProjectStrings.userInfoEntityName)
                
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "isStudent == %d", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
                fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
                print(predicate)
                
                do{
                    result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    
                    let fetchedRecord = result.filter({$0.email ?? "" == txtEmail.text})
                    print("Fetched record--->\(fetchedRecord)")
                    
                    if fetchedRecord.count != 0 {
                        
                        let object = fetchedRecord.first!
                        
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.profileImage, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.profileImage)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.isStudent, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.isStudent)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.firstName, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.firstName)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.lastName, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.lastName)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.email, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.email)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.password, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.password)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.birthDate, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.birthDate)
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(object.gender, forKey: Constants.UserDictionaryKeys.gender)
                        
                        if object.password == txtPassword.text {
                            print("Password match, Successful logIn")
                            
                            let storyBoardTeacher = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardTeacher", bundle: nil)
            
            let storyBoardStudent = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardStudent", bundle: nil)
            
            let homeTeacherVC = storyBoardTeacher.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeTeacherVC") as! HomeTeacherVC
            
            let homeStudentVC = storyBoardStudent.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeStudentVC") as! HomeStudentVC
            
            if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
    print("Teacher log in successful!")
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeTeacherVC, animated: true)
            }else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
    print("Teacher log in successful!")
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(homeStudentVC, animated: true)
            }
                            
                            txtEmail.text = ""
                            txtPassword.text = ""
                            
                        } else {
                            print("Incorrect password")
                            Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Incorrect Password", userMessage: "Please enter correct password to proceed", vc: self)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Utils.shareInstance.displayMyAlertMessage(title: "Account doesn't exist", userMessage: "No account found for this e-mail address! Please Sign up to proceed", vc: self)
                    }
                }catch{
                    print("error")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: please add more comment and description for what resolved your problem